# How to calculate the Lambda of Poisson distribution from mean of inter arrival time?

Tags: statistics, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions

I have interarrival times in a system with mean equal to $0.45$. Does $\lambda = \frac{1}{0.45}$ if I need to select Poisson as an arrival distribution?

Comment: The interarrival times have exponential distribution mean $\frac{1}{\lambda}$, so yes.

Answer (score 1):

The interarrival times have exponential distribution mean $\frac{1}{\lambda}$, so yes.